# How to create sub directory in DiskLruCache?

Tags: android, android-lru-cache

I'm using DiskLruCache in my project. It works great but I would like to know if it's possible to create sub directories under the root cache directory.

- DiskLruCache is a popular project on https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache

For example:

```
MainCache (Create by DiskLruCache.open function with 1GB limit)
    |
    --> Dir A
    |      |
    |      ---> Dir C
    |
    |
    --> Dir B
```

The total size of files under MainCache and its subdirectory should still be complied with 1GB policy.

Comment: there is no DiskLruCache  class in the Android  SDK

Comment: DiskLruCache is a popular project on https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache

Comment: I don't really see the point of directories in a disk cache. what would you use them for?

Comment: I want to avoid FAT32 directory file limit. FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651907/is-there-a-limit-for-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-on-an-sd-card